# Error in mysql algorithmic query

Tags: mysql, algorithm, math

I am trying to get the users that I have and to multiply by the price of pack 1.

But i receive an error from this line.

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(user_subscriptions.created_at) = 2012 THEN 1*(SELECT packs.price from packs where packs.id = 1) ELSE 0 END ) AS 'USD-TOTAL-2012',
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please cut and paste the complete error message.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(user_subscriptions.created_at) = 2012.....

Comment: i already fixed! tks i had the error in the previous line tks